# Why is the init file not populating Memory Tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, init

For optimizing system performance, we are storing a few static tables on RAM (copies of which does exist on the hard-drive as well -- on the MyISAM). Now, as we all know, when the server re-starts all data on RAM gets deleted. Hence to avoid that we created an init file that has 4 SQL statements.

Please note that each SQL statement exists on a separate line, ended with a semi-colon (;) and there are no comments anywhere --- so from my limited knowledge, I believe that I have avoided making some basic mistakes. However, when I re-start MySQL manually from the command line to test it, I see that the memory tables are empty. There are no issues with the initfile itself, because when I execute the initfile manually from the command line, the data gets populated without any issues.

Any help in terms of resolving this will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Udayan

Comment: What are the contents of your init file?  Where is it located?  And, what is the command line you are using to start your server?

Comment: Presumably you have no error logging in the init script. You've provided no details of how this script is invoked nor the OS this runs on - hence it's not posible to provide any answer.

Comment: @ JayDM -- There are 4 statements: INSERT INTO _active_properties_memory SELECT * FROM _active_properties;
INSERT INTO _airports_memory SELECT * FROM _airports;
INSERT INTO _countries_memory SELECT * FROM _countries;
INSERT INTO _points_of_interest_memory SELECT * FROM _points_of_interest; The file is located in the tmp folder for the root user -- when I execute the show global variables SQL statement, the filepath is showing up correctly

Comment: @symcbean --- this is running on Linux OS -- my understanding was that init is executed everytime the server restarts without having to invoke anything.

Comment: init runs lots of things in a very well defined order - there are lots of ways to hook into it. You still haven't explained how/when it gets run.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right here.

Just to check, I tried restarting my local mysql server using /etc/init.d/mysql restart.  And, it started up as running by the mysql user (not root).

So, we will need the following to try to figure this out because I am just about positive that the problem is either that the file has the wrong permissions or it is in a location that the user running mysqld does not have access to.

- What version of Linux are you running?
- What is the version of mySQL that you have installed?
- Is 'init-file=' in the right section of my.cnf?
- What is the output of 'ps -ef | grep mysqld'?
- What is the output of 'ls -lrt /tmp/initfile.sql'?
- What did you mean by 'There are no issues with the initfile itself,
  because when I execute the initfile manually from the command line,
  the data gets populated without any issues.'?

I cannot help but think that it is a permissions problem.  So the fourth and fifth answers are the ones that I am most interested in.

You should add all of these answers to your question - so that people have everything they need to help you solve your problem.

Comment: we are running Linux. While testing it, I have been restarting the server as the root user --- also when the server restarts periodically, I am pretty certain it is being done by the root user as well --- hence the tmp directory should not be the problem -- any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you check which user it is actually running as though?  Type 'ps -ef | grep mysql' to see.  Linux systems usually start the service as 'mysql' even if you start the script as root.

Comment: What exactly are the command line you are using and the entry in you my.cnf file that sets the init-file?

Comment: init_file=/tmp/initfile.sql initfile.sql being the file that has the 4 SQL statements (I know --- imaginative!)

Comment: You said that you are starting the server manually - what command are you typing: /usr/sbin/mysqld --init-file=/tmp/initfile.sql?  Or are you using service mysql start?  /etc/init.d/mysql start? Something else?

Comment: To restart MySQL I am using /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all your suggestions but I have figured out what the issues were.

1. In the SQL file I needed to mention which database that init-file should populate.
2. I had trailing semi-colons in the SQL statements -- apparently that is not a good idea.

Once I made these two small changes, everything started working fine.

Again, thanks for the pointers!

Udayan